# Get last value of previous partition/group in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe looking like this (just some example values):

```
| id |         timestamp           |  mode   |  trip  |  journey  |  value  |
  1     2021-09-12 23:59:19.717000   walking      1         1         1.21
  1     2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000   walking      1         1         1.36
  1     2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000   driving      2         1         1.65
  2     2021-09-11 23:52:09.315000   walking      4         6         1.04
```

I want to create new columns which I fill with the previous and next mode. Something like this:

```
| id |         timestamp           |  mode   |  trip  |  journey  |  value  | prev     | next
  1     2021-09-12 23:59:19.717000   walking      1         1         1.21    bus       driving
  1     2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000   walking      1         1         1.36    bus       driving
  1     2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000   driving      2         1         1.65    walking   walking
  2     2021-09-11 23:52:09.315000   walking      4         6         1.0     walking   driving
```

I have tried to partition by id, trip, journey and mode and ordered by timestamp. Then I tried to use `lag()` and `lead()` but I am not sure these work on other partitions. I came across the `Window.unboundedPreceding` and `Window.unboundedFollowing`, however I am not sure I completely understand how these work. In my mind I think that if I partition the data as explained above I will always just need the last value of `mode` from the previous partition and to fill the next I could reorder the partition from ascending to descending on the timestamp and then do the same to fill the next column. However, I am unsure how I get the last value of the previous partition.

I have tried this:

```
   w = Window.partitionBy("id", "journey", "trip").orderBy(col("timestamp").asc())
    w_prev = w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,  Window.unboundedFollowing)
    
    df = df.withColumn("prev", first("mode").over(w_prev))
```

Code examples and explainations using pyspark will be very appreciated!

Comment: A question, Do you want to fill the previous mode to the next unique set of `id, journey, and trip`? For example, If I have `1|1|1` as pair of `id|journey|trip` and another one with `1|1|2` , so here you are asking for the previous mode to be filled with last mode from `1|1|1`?

Comment: Yes correct. So typically a different trip will have a different mode (not necessarily though). So basically there can be several trips within a journey for a given id and I want to get the mode from the previous trip of that same id.

Comment: What if there are no next trips within a journey? what should be the next mode? `Null`? and the same other way around, if it is the first trip it will not have any previous mode, so in that situation it should be what? `Null'?

Comment: Yes that would be fine.

Comment: Can you explain how the values 'Bus' and 'driving' getting populated? Can you add the example rows from where these values are coming?

Comment: It is a dataset I have stored in a database. So I select the table and try to discern the previous and next mode given a unique id, trip number and journey number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on what I could understand you could do something like this,

Create a partition based on ID and their journey, within each journey there are multiple trips, so order by trip and lastly the timestamp, and then simply use the lead and lag to get the output!

```
w = Window().partitionBy('id', 'journey').orderBy('trip', 'timestamp')

df.withColumn('prev', F.lag('mode', 1).over(w)) \
    .withColumn('next', F.lead('mode', 1).over(w)) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------------+-------+----+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|id |timestamp                 |mode   |trip|journey|value|prev   |next   |
+---+--------------------------+-------+----+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|1  |2021-09-12 23:59:19.717000|walking|1   |1      |1.21 |null   |walking|
|1  |2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000|walking|1   |1      |1.36 |walking|driving|
|1  |2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000|driving|2   |1      |1.65 |walking|null   |
|2  |2021-09-11 23:52:09.315000|walking|4   |6      |1.04 |null   |null   |
+---+--------------------------+-------+----+-------+-----+-------+-------+
```

**EDIT**:

Okay as OP asked, you can do this to achieve it,

```
# Used for taking the latest record from same id, trip, journey
w = Window().partitionBy('id', 'trip', 'journey').orderBy(F.col('timestamp').desc())

# Used to calculate prev and next mode
w1 = Window().partitionBy('id', 'journey').orderBy('trip')
```

```
# First take only the latest rows for a particular combination of id, trip, journey
# Second, use the filtered rows to get prev and next modes

df2 = df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w)) \
    .filter(F.col('rn') == 1) \
    .withColumn('prev', F.lag('mode', 1).over(w1)) \
    .withColumn('next', F.lead('mode', 1).over(w1)) \
    .drop('rn')

df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------------+-------+----+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|id |timestamp                 |mode   |trip|journey|value|prev   |next   |
+---+--------------------------+-------+----+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|1  |2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000|walking|1   |1      |1.36 |null   |driving|
|1  |2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000|driving|2   |1      |1.65 |walking|null   |
|2  |2021-09-11 23:52:09.315000|walking|4   |6      |1.04 |null   |null   |
+---+--------------------------+-------+----+-------+-----+-------+-------+
```

```
# Finally, join the calculated DF with the original DF to get prev and next mode

final_df = df.alias('a').join(df2.alias('b'), ['id', 'trip', 'journey'], how='left') \
    .select('a.*', 'b.prev', 'b.next')

final_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-------+--------------------------+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|id |trip|journey|timestamp                 |mode   |value|prev   |next   |
+---+----+-------+--------------------------+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|1  |1   |1      |2021-09-12 23:59:19.717000|walking|1.21 |null   |driving|
|1  |1   |1      |2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000|walking|1.36 |null   |driving|
|1  |2   |1      |2021-09-12 23:59:38.617000|driving|1.65 |walking|null   |
|2  |4   |6      |2021-09-11 23:52:09.315000|walking|1.04 |null   |null   |
+---+----+-------+--------------------------+-------+-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: This didn't work. I ended up getting different modes in prev and next within the same id, trip and journey.

Comment: Could you provide me an example of the failed case?

Comment: Sorry, I reran it so I don't have the example anymore (and it will take a while to run it again), However for the same id, trip and journey I got different modes in prev and next. For instance given id=1, trip=1 and journey=1 I had rows containing both driving and walking while there should only be 1 mode corresponding to the next mode and only 1 corresponding to the previous mode

Comment: So you mean to say that you don't want more than one mode per `id+trip+journey`? Like in the example I have shown in the output check the 1st and 2nd row, you don't want it like that?

Comment: Well, sorry it looked right at first glance but no if for the first row there are no previous trips for that specific id, within the journey then all values in prev for that id+trip+journey should be null. Otherwise all values in prev/next should be the same for any given id+trip+journey

Comment: Check the EDIT Section and tell me if it works for you